# Angular with wordpress jwt auth

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I'm trying to make wordpress as a backend to my angularjs app, so I'm using the plugin rest-api with the jwt-auth 
so when trying to login I get the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/back/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://imider.ma' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I know i have to add CROS access, but I'm not familiar with wordpress, so any help?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/17zgUHZrvL5KVG2yKQE8NWgxNZn6V08xr65DBox5WVZ0/edit?usp=sharing

here is my tutorial of how to access the api

then you can use this to get the token

```
$http({
                method:'post',
                url:'',
                data: {
                    username: '',
                    password: ''
                }
            }).then(function(results){
                console.log(results);
            })
```

then you can use this

```
$http({
                    method:'get',
                    url:'',
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <myTokenId>' }
                }).then(function(results){
                    console.log(results);
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a video detailing the process of installing and setting up the plugin. If you follow the steps I outlined there you should be good.

https://youtu.be/Mp7T7x1oxDk

The idea is that you also need to modify `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` to make the plugin work with the existing API endpoints as well.

Just by installing the plugin and adding a SECRET_KEY, used to sign the token will make the JWT setup work but it will not allow you to use the tokens generated through that API with the existing REST API endpoints.